CORS Issues with Slim PHP API - "Http failure response: 0 Unknown Error"
I'm experiencing CORS-related issues when making requests to my Slim PHP API from my Angular application. I'm getting the following error message in the console:

Error from client log console: XHROPTIONS
http://localhost:8080/api/validate CORS Missing Allow Credentials
Bloccata richiesta multiorigine (cross-origin): il criterio di
corrispondenza dell’origine non consente la lettura della risorsa
remota da http://localhost:8080/api/validate. Motivo: previsto “true”
in header CORS “Access-Control-Allow-Credentials”.
Bloccata richiesta multiorigine (cross-origin): il criterio di
corrispondenza dell’origine non consente la lettura della risorsa
remota da http://localhost:8080/api/validate. Motivo: richiesta CORS
non riuscita. Codice di stato: (null).
Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api/validate: 0
Unknown Error

Here is my middleware code:
php
  $fitnetApi->slim->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
        $uri = $request->getUri()->getPath();
        
        // Controlla se l'URI inizia con '/api'
        if (strpos($uri, '/api') === 0) {
            $cookies = $request->getCookieParams();
            $token = $cookies['jwt_token'] ?? null; // Usa l'operatore null coalescing

    
            // Se non c'è un token, continua con il middleware successivo
            if (!$token) {
                return $response
                ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                ->withStatus(401)
                ->write(json_encode([
                    "status" => "error",
                    "message" => "token invalid"
                ], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
            }
    
            try {
                // Decodifica il token
                $decoded = JWT::decode($token, new Key('', 'HS256'));
    
                // Controlla se il token è scaduto
                if (isset($decoded->exp) && $decoded->exp < time()) {
                    
                    $rtoken = $cookies['rjwt_token'] ?? null;;
                    $decRjwt = JWT::decode($rtoken, new Key('', 'HS256'));
    
                    // Controlla se il rtoken esiste e non è scaduto
                    if ($decRjwt && isset($decRjwt->exp) && $decRjwt->exp > time()) {
                        // Rigenera un token
                        $newToken = JWT::encode(
                            [
                                'id' => $decoded->id,
                                'type' => $decoded->type,
                                'exp' => time() + 60 * 15 // 15 minuti
                            ],
                            "",
                            "HS256"
                        );
    
                        // Aggiunge il nuovo token come attributo alla richiesta
                        $request = $request->withAttribute('new_token', $newToken);
                    } else {
                        // Se il rtoken è scaduto, restituisci un errore
                        return $response
                            ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            ->withStatus(401)
                            ->write(json_encode([
                                "status" => "error",
                                "message" => "rtoken expired, renew auth"
                            ], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
                    }
                }
            } catch (ExpiredException $e) {
                // Gestisci il caso in cui il token JWT è scaduto
                return $response
                    ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    ->withStatus(401)
                    ->write(json_encode([
                        "status" => "error",
                        "message" => "Token expired"
                    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
            } catch (SignatureInvalidException $e) {
                // Gestisci il caso in cui il token JWT è invalido
                return $response
                    ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    ->withStatus(401)
                    ->write(json_encode([
                        "status" => "error",
                        "message" => "Invalid token signature"
                    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // Gestione generica di eccezioni JWT
                return $response
                    ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    ->withStatus(401)
                    ->write(json_encode([
                        "status" => "error",
                        "message" => "Invalid token"
                    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
            }
        }
    
        // Continua con il prossimo middleware o la route
        return $next($request, $response);
    });

cors settings in middleware:
 $fitnetApi->slim->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\CorsMiddleware([
        "origin" => ["http://localhost:8100"],
        "methods" => ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
        "headers.allow" => ["Token", "Authorization", "If-Match", "If-Unmodified-Since", "Content-Type"],
        "headers.expose" => ["Authorization"],
        "credentials" => true,
        "cache" => 0,
    ]));

The error occurs when making a POST request to http://localhost:8080/api/validate.
Despite the CORS headers being set, I still receive an "Unknown Error" with a status of 0.
I've verified that the backend is running on localhost:8080.
The API responds correctly to requests made through Postman.
I've checked for JavaScript errors in the Angular application.
What could be causing these CORS issues, and how can I fix the error so that my Angular application can communicate with the Slim PHP API successfully?
Any help would be appreciated!

As the initial request mentioned in the error message is an OPTIONS request, it's possible it isn't handled by PHP at all, but by the webserver. What webserver are you using to serve the PHP code? You may need to configure it to pass HTTP OPTIONS requests to the PHP engine, this is not always done by default. If that's happening, it might explain why headers you've set in the middleware are not actually being returned by the webserver in this case.

@ADyson i am using apache. Hosted in localhost by mac OS. maybe I should edit the .htaccess?

I haven't actually done that configuration myself anyway, but the internet seems to have a lot of suggestions for how to configure it, so I doubt you need to ask anyone personally to tell you how to do it. Try and get it working based on the plentful information which already exists about this topic. If you still can't do it, [edit] the question to show what you've tried and explain any issues you encountered.

@ADyson I tried to reconfigure cors, even modifying .htaccess, I still get the same error, an error that doesn't occur if I remove the piece of jwt authentication code shown in the question. very strange

In which order are you adding your middlewares?

@Olivier here my full middleware: https://codeshare.io/7JXMlE

@Conta Please go through https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/cookbook/enable-cors.html specially option routing
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
return $response;
});

@BhaskarJain Note that the OP is using Slim 3, not 4.

you need to handle OPTIONS Requests in Slim by adding the handler seperately
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
return $response;
});

Refer : https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/enable-cors.html
you can also try adding CORS header directly in Apache ,
try adding this to .htaccess
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8100"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Token, Authorization, If-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Content-Type"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
</IfModule>


tried adding this at middleware start:
        $response = $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100') 
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        return $response;
    });

but I still get cors error on client side

Have you tried a proxy configuration in Angular to bypass CORS issues?
try creating a proxy.conf.json and then
try
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

Ref : https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/angular-cors-guide-examples-and-how-to-enable-it/

nice idea, I'll check it out. However I don't know why but I'm noticing that if I check directly in the authentication method like this:
        $uri = $request->getUri()->getPath();
        
        // Imposta gli header CORS
        $response = $response
            ->[...]
        if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
            return $response;
        }```
the current problems don't appear... it's strange

I'd like to point out that in your Tuupola\Middleware\CorsMiddleware instance you indicated as origin http://localhost:8100 but your are on port 8080 so that could be a starting point.
if this doesn't work I suggest lazy CORS handling, as indicated in slim doc, here's an example:
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');


The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must contain the client URL (i.e. the origin from which the requests come), right?  not the server URL. the port: 8100 is my client application, 8080: instead the rest api runs there

To my knowledge and my experience the origin is intended to be the server, CORS exist to prevent cross origin call.
Let's say you contact localhost:8080 to get your html, css and scripts and at some point you need to fetch the data, you are going to call localhost:8080/api/something and this is still on the same origin.
If you host you api on a different host, let's assume localhost:8081 so localhost:8081/api/something, i think CORS will identify this as a different host so you need to authorize that too

I've never used Slim, but I think the header(Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is probably getting overridden with a diff port in the middleware later in the code that you have shared(see line 43). Also you seems to have missed one line that I've added below.
So the closure code should probably start something like this:
$fitnetApi->slim->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
        $uri = $request->getUri()->getPath();
        $res = $next($req, $res); // you forgot this line
        // Imposta gli header CORS
        $res = $res
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100') // Cambia con l'URL del frontend
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    // Gestisci le richieste OPTIONS
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
        return $response;
    }

    // Prosegui solo se l'URI inizia con '/api'
    if (strpos($uri, '/api') === 0) {
        $cookies = $request->getCookieParams();
        $token = $cookies['jwt_token'] ?? null;

If that did not work, try this
$res = $res->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 

